# Complex numbers; trigonometric properties

Tags: complex-numbers

I have trouble doing this exercise:

Let $z = cosθ + isinθ$
Expand $(z + z^{−1})^6 and (z-z^{−1})^6$
Hence show that $cos^6θ+sin^6θ=1/8(3cos4θ+5)$

I expanded these two brackets and I got:
$2cos6θ+12cos4θ+30cos2θ+20$ for the first one and
$2cos6θ-12cos4θ+30cos2θ-20$ for the second one

Is that correct?

I also know that 
$(z + z^{−1})^6$ is $64cos^6θ$ and 
$(z-z^{−1})^6$ is $64sin^6θ$

but when I add these two result it doesn't work

Where do I make the mistake?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I reckon that $(z-z^{-1})^6$ is actually $-64\sin^6 \theta$,

Answer (score 1):

$$z-z^{-1}=2i\sin\theta\implies(z-z^{-1})^6=(2\sin\theta)^6i^6=-64\sin^6\theta$$

$$64(\cos^6\theta+\sin^6\theta)=(z+z^{-1})^6-(z-z^{-1})^6=2\left[\binom61\left(z^4+z^{-4}\right)+\binom63\right]$$

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: I don't really understand the second line of your answer. So far I got: 24cos4θ+40 which gives us 8(3cos4θ+5) and not 1/8(3cos4θ+5). Could tell me what I'm doing wrong? ;)

Comment: @Markowska, Have you noticed $64$ in the left hand side?

Comment: Oh! yes, now i can divide it by 64. Thanks a lot